# Is a disputed flag still reviewed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

In [Triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18406539) I came across this question:

*[Obtaining a list of the scores of words having a user-defined length from Scrabble word list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065326/obtaining-a-list-of-the-scores-of-words-having-a-user-defined-length-from-scrabb)*

I raised a flag because the problem was caused by a simple programming error and the question won't be helpful for anyone else.

Apparently three other reviewers thought this question looks ok (which I agree it does if you don't read the comments) which caused my flag along with someone else's to be disputed.

While I couldn't care less if my flag was marked as helpful or disputed, I still think this question should be closed or deleted. So, if a flag is disputed in this scenario, will it still be shown to moderators to evaluate if there is something to it or is this the end of the story and we just have to live with the fact, that sometimes the consensus in a review process is not that accurate?

Comment: Close flags are never shown to moderators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Close flags aren't *ever* shown to moderators (they can of course see them if they care to look, but they aren't responsible for handling them).  Close flags are only ever shown to community reviewers for handling.  If the reviewers felt that the flag wasn't worth acting on and disputed it, then the flag is handled; there isn't anyone else that's going to look at it again.

Note that if you feel that a question isn't useful you should be reflecting that opinion by downvoting it, as that's precisely what downvotes are for.

Comment: It surprises me how many people _flag_ questions and somehow avoid _voting_ on them. I could understand it on answers, since it has a cost... but on questions?

Comment: @yivi Downvoting doesn't do much, and might actually give more reputation / score than it takes, considering upvoters sometimes actively trying to counter downvotes they disagree with. I'm surprised how many people downvote or comment with close-worthy criticism without flagging or voting to close.

Comment: @Dukeling. It's not about the "punishment", so that the OP would end up "gaining" rep is no really an issue for me. The fact that people would vote to "correct" downvotes on closable questions is bad enough, but votes should signal quality. An off-topic question can't be said to be a good quality question. That people won't downvote closable question also end up tripping people in reviews and review-audits. IMO, off-topic flag/vote and down-vote should go in tandem.

Comment: And if down-voting can be bad because people can vote the other way to "correct" for your votes... then I guess _all_ voting can be detrimental? I don't think that makes a lot of sense

Comment: And by down-voting you give roomba a chance if the closure fails. Roomba needs to eat, too. :)

Comment: @yivi I'm more trying to say that a single downvote considered mostly in isolation doesn't do much (especially in my experience of either disagreeing or agreeing with the majority - -10->-11 feels like it does more harm than good and +10->+9 will probably get countered, 0->+/-1 is more useful). When looking at the bigger picture, voting is certainly (somewhat) useful.

Comment: Considering the example under discussion is currently +/-2, this concern is a bit irrelevant, @dukeling - any vote stands to have a significant effect, and flaggers still out number downvotes.

Comment: @Shog9 It's always relevant. If both sides (downvoting on high and low score) are potentially actively harmful and only the middle is potentially vaguely useful, it's really hard to figure out where those lines is supposed to be, or if there even are any lines. It doesn't help that I seem to have a strong leaning towards strongly disagreeing with the majority over posts I actually care about.

Comment: Considering the volume of posts with 0 votes (and, naturally, score) it strikes me as a concern that will - on balance - do more harm than good. For every wasted or counter-productive vote, there are scores of posts that could benefit from a honest evaluation and get none.

Comment: @Shog9 Isn't the [so] philosophy to not care about posts that almost no-one sees (based on close-vote aging, Roomba, etc.?)?

Comment: In this scenario, someone is by definition looking at it, @dukeling. Voting can influence future visibility, which feeds into the rest of what you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I didn't even know who will be shown a close flag. Also thanks to everyone for that great discussion about voting on questions. I always felt like downvotes are the right way to deal with bad answers and only flag the really terrible ones while I usually only use upvotes or flags on questions. I guess I should reconsider.

Comment: @mmgross You don't use flags for "really terrible" content.  You use votes to indicate whether you think something is of good or bad quality.  You use flags when something violates the rules in some way that requires moderation action (i.e. deletion, closure, locking, etc.).  While there is certainly lots of overlap between bad content and content that required moderation action from flagging, they are two different things.

Comment: Sorry @Servy I was not specific enough: By "really terrible" I don't mean actual answers that are just bad or even wrong. What I meant was I flag answers only if they are either spam or NAA.

Comment: @yivi A way that happens is when I run out of downvotes before I run out of close votes. Visiting a tag like [tag:grub] or [tag:kali-linux] quickly consumes both, but there are some questions there which only deserve a downvote, and not a close vote or flag. Sounds like I need to find a better hobby now that I review this comment, though ...